# How to refresh / reload Grid

Tags: javascript, extjs

hi this is my code i am trying to refresh grid panel on clicking refresh button in toolbar , but it wont work anymore or nothing happens  can you please help me  what is the proper syntax  ?

```
var store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    url: 'data-cloud.php',
    fields: [{
        name: 'userid'
    }, {
        name: 'record_name'
    }, {
        name: 'search_term',
        type: 'string'
    }]
});

var grid_array = new Array();
store.load({
    params: {
        start: 0,
        limit: 5
    }
});

store.on('load', function(store, records) {
    for (var j = 0; j < records.length; j++) {
        grid_array[j] = records[j].get('record_name');
    }
});

// create the Grid
var datagrid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
    store: store,
    columns: [{
        id: 'id',
        header: 'Cloud Name',
        width: 155,
        renderer: record_name,
        sortable: true,
        dataIndex: 'record_name'
    }, {
        header: 'Search Term',
        width: 150,
        sortable: true,
        dataIndex: 'search_term'
    }],
    stripeRows: true,
    height: 250,
    width: 500,
    id: 'cloud_panel',
    title: 'DB Grid',
    id: 'detailPanel',
    tbar: [{
            text: 'Refresh',
            iconCls: 'new-topic',
            handler: function() {
                Ext.getCmp('detailPanel').getView().refresh();
            }
        }

    ],
    bbar: new Ext.PagingToolbar({
        pageSize: 5,
        store: store,
        displayInfo: true,
        displayMsg: 'Displaying topics {0} - {1} of {2}',
        emptyMsg: "No topics to display"
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var grid = Ext.getCmp('cloud_panel');
...
tbar: [
   handler: function() {
       grid.load();
   }
]
```

Comment: i used your code it goes in long loading console shows error line GET http://192.168.1.2/ext/undefined :(

Comment: i used this also Ext.getCmp('cloud_panel').load('data-cloud.php'); after that it directly print array in the grid rather than actaul values.. ! :(

Comment: thank to you also. . ! my problem get solved. . by Ext.getCmp('cloud_panel').getStore().reload();

Answer (score 0):

If you refresh the grid's view, the data will **not** be loaded again, it will just re-render the presentation.

To refresh the actual data, use the [reload](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-reload) function on the grid's store:

```
Ext.getCmp('detailPanel').getStore().reload();
```

Btw, you're setting the `id` property twice in your grid's configuration, "cloud_panel" and "detailPanel", so you'll probably want to eliminate one of them.

Comment: i have remove the twice id then it works. .. Thank you so much. .  its working nice . . ! :)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var grid = Ext.getCmp('cloud_panel');
grid.getStore().load();
```

also you can pass params to store

```
grid.getStore().getProxy().extraParams = {name:'name1', lname: 'lname'}
```

and after

```
grid.getStore().load(function(){
    alert('store was loaded');
});
```